# Building a list of Dictionaries gives a ValueError

Tags: python, list, dictionary, django-views

I'm having an issue building a list of dictionaries like this

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):
    user = StaticHelpers.user_to_subclass(request.user)[1]
    user_type = StaticHelpers.user_to_subclass(request.user)[0]

    if user_type == "Patient":
        apps = StaticHelpers.find_appointments(user)
        events = []
        for app in apps:
            events.append({
                'title': str(app.doctor),
                'start': str(app.start_time),
                'end': str(app.end_time)
            })
        return render(request, 'HealthApp/patientIndex.html', events)
    elif user_type == "Doctor" or user_type == "Nurse":
        return render(request, 'HealthApp/doctorIndex.html')
    elif user_type == "Admin":
        return render(request, 'HealthApp/doctorIndex.html')
```

Each dictionary needs to have those 3 values, and I need a list of them. However it just spits out this error at me

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/devin-matte/Documents/Healthnet/trunk/HealthApp/views.py", line 23, in home
    return render(request, 'HealthApp/patientIndex.html', events)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 97, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 92, in render
    context = make_context(context, request)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 291, in make_context
    context.push(original_context)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 61, in push
    return ContextDict(self, *dicts, **kwargs)
  File "/home/devin-matte/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 20, in __init__
    super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
[05/Mar/2017 19:56:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 99419
```

Comment: That code does not cause that error. Please post all the relevant code, and the full traceback.

Comment: I added the full method and traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback shows that the problem is nothing to do with creating the dictionaries, but in how you send them to the template. The third argument to `render` must be a dict, where the keys are the name you want to use to refer to that value in the template. So:

```
return render(request, 'HealthApp/patientIndex.html', {"events": events})
```

Now you can iterate through `events` in the template.